# ng-repeat depend on value of md-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

select in md-option with value of number and I define value to 1 as 
`ng-selected="$first"`

```
$scope.roomsHotel = ('1 2 3 4 5').split(' ').map(function(roomsHotel) {
    return {number: roomsHotel};
```

how I can make `ng-repeat` for whole div depent on number of `roomsHotel`
I read another questions and documentation but still cannot find the way .

Can anybody help me on this matter please?

maybe with photo easier 
[image]

I would like to `ng-repeat` this div depend on value of room and on render page it show first one
Ps:

I try `ng-repeat="(key, value) in roomsHotel"` but its show all 5 on start and try
`ng-repeat="(key, value) in roomsHotel.value"` but don't show at start

Thanks

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking, please clarify